# Automatically add " & disown" to commands beginning with "text_editor"?

Tags: shell, command-line, background-process

open a file with a text editor:

```
text_editor test.txt
```

I would like it to be executed as if it was..

```
text_editor test.txt & disown
```

Comment: If you want to avoid `SIGHUP`, you better look into `nohup`. More portable, even POSIX-compatible.

Comment: Bind a function to the string text_editor

Answer (score 1):

If your `text_editor` is always the same use a shell function.

```
text_editor(){
    /usr/bin/text_editor "$@" & disown
}
```

Put this snippet into `~/.bashrc`, then restart your shell.

This works by replacing the command `text_editor` with a shell function, that in turn executes the command you intended to run.

Comment: You can use `command text_editor` to avoid hard-coding the path.